# splitting item in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

[Original Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UdvDg/92/)

[Failed Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UdvDg/96/)

Here's the returned data:

```
var availableTags = [
    'ActionScript|AppleScript|Asp',
    'BASIC',
    'Clojure|C++|C|COBOL|ColdFusion',
    'Erlang',
    'Fortran',
    'Groovy',
    'Haskell',
    'Java|JavaScript',
    'Lisp',
    'Perl|PHP|Python',
    'Ruby',
    'Scala|Scheme',
];
```

How can I split the items into arrays during the `renderItem` function,and when users type PHP it will only return PHP from 'Perl|PHP|Python'?

Here's my code:

```
$('#tags').autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    search: function(event, ui) {
        $('#wrapper').empty();
    },
})
.data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $('<div class="element"></div>')
        .data('item.autocomplete', item)
    var smallchoice = item.label.split('|');                    
    $.each(smallchoice,function(j,smallchoice){
           $option = '<a href="#" >' + smallchoice+ '</a>'
         })

        .append($option)
        .appendTo($('#wrapper'));
};
```

Comment: You need to make an effort to understand the method chaining you are using. You have just chucked some code into the middle of your chain - which has broken it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what you trying to do.

```
.data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
  var inp = $("#tags").val();
  var items = item.label.split("|");
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      index = items[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(inp.toUpperCase());
      if (index == 0 || index > 0) {
          item = items[i];
          return $('<div class="element"></div>')
          .data('item.autocomplete', item)
          .append('<a href="#">' + item + '</a>')
          .appendTo($('#wrapper'));
      }
  }
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UdvDg/99/)